# JsonSerializationException

Tags: c#

Self referencing loop detected for property 'normalized' with type Vector3

Почему я получаю данную ошибку?Вроде все правильно добавляю и сохраняю

```
Api.PlayerCache[player.Uid].Home.Add(player.Location);
DC4_API.JsonHelper.SaveFile(Api.PlayerCache, "config/playerConnection.json");
```

Comment: Вам же ответил сам компилятор. Vector3 содержит свойство normalized, которое возвращает Vector3. Попытка сериализовать это вводит сериализатор в цикл.

Comment: @test123 возможно ли как то остановить этот цикл?

Comment: Вот варианты решения: 1. Сделайте normalized методом, 2. Сделайте normalized  статиком.

Comment: Вы это в Юнити делаете? Можете использовать свою прослойку при хранении и сериализации для Vector3 .

Comment: Ну, забыл ещё такой вариант, можете погуглить атрибуты для json сериализатора, и сделать что то вроде NonSerialize, конкретно для поля normalized

Answer (score 0):

Погуглил за вас

- [Вариант](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10169648/how-to-exclude-property-from-json-serialization) с отменой сериализации поля normalized через атрибут [[ScriptIgnore]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.scriptignoreattribute.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- Замените свойство Vector3 normalized { get { ... } } на метод, например (подходит, если нормализованный вектор вычисляется на базе текущего):

  ```
  public Vector3 normalized(Vector3 vector) { ... } // вместо this, используйте vector
  ```
- Сделайте метод статиком, например (подходит, если нормализованный вектор един для всех):

  ```
  static Vector3 normalized { get {... } }
  ```
- В случае, если вы не можете менять Vector3, и предыдущие 3 пункта не подходят, используйте прослойку, которая самостоятельно будет хранить x,y,z, в своих полях.

Вот вам пример прослойки:

```
    using System;

    [Serialize]
    public class ExampleVector3 {

        public float x { get; set; }
        public float y { get; set; }
        public float z { get; set; }

        public ExampleVector3(Vector3 vector){
            x = vector.x;
            y = vector.y;
            z = vector.z;
        }

        public Vector3 ToVector(){
            return new Vector3(x,y,z);
        }

    }
```

использовать можно так:

```
List<ExampleVector3> home = new List<ExampleVector3>();
home.Add(new ExampleVector3(player.Location));
```

Comment: я вообще не использую normalized - я хз откуда он public List<Vector3> Home { get; set; }

Comment: @Сергей, приведите содержимое Vector3. Далее, ответьте на вопрос, это ваш вектор, или это часть библиотеки?

Comment: normalized находится внутри Vector3. Он является свойством этого класса, или структуры, не знаю что это у вас.

Comment: Vector3 находиться в библиотеке unity - я его не менял.Вот так добавляю  var pl = new Users
            {
                Name = player.Name,
                Ip = player.Ip,
                TimeOnline = player.TimeOnline,
            };
            if (pl.Home == null)
            {
                pl.Home = new List<Vector3>();
            }

Comment: Да мне этот код не важен. Я же вам указал причину ошибки. Используйте последнее предложение из моего списка. Нужен промежуточный класс. Вектор юнити в вашем сериализаторе сериализовать не получится. Попробуйте для теста сделать сериализацию, например Vector3.zero. Я ожидаю того, что у вас это не получится сделать.

Comment: я не знаю как это сделать

Comment: @Сергей, отредактировал ответ